# React Native Storybook - TypeError: identifier.indexOf is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, storybook

Running yarn storybook (start-storybook) is throwing
**TypeError: identifier.indexOf is not a function** in `/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js`

react-storybook version - 5.3.12

Comment: have you solved the issue? Am getting precisely that same error